# How can I find a redirect to a custom protocol

Tags: linux, firefox, xorg, redirection, uri

I am trying to launch Zoom using a crontab on my X11 based Linux system. When [clicking](https://zoom.us/j/123456789) `Join Meeting` Firefox gives me a redirect notice, but doesn't actually give me the full URI, is there any way I can find the URI being called?

Zoom uses the `zoommtg://` custom protocol, and I've gotten some functionality working, but I would really prefer a solution that could be applied to any page with obfuscated redirects.
Ive already tried developer tools but the code is obfuscated. I intend to use xdg-open to launch my meetings when I find the URI

Comment: Did you try the network view in developer tools? This should show you the full URL for any HTTP requests Firefox makes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The page itself logs the URL to the "Console" tab of Chrome's *Developer Tools*:

> `Launched external handler for 'zoommtg://zoom.us/join?action=join&confno=123456789&zc=64&confid=dXRpZD[...]mMTZl&browser=chrome'.`

You can of course make a custom xdg-open handler (or even an xdg-open wrapper, or a 'zoom' substitute script) that'll log the opened URI somewhere, or use one of the available system tracing mechanisms to log all commands being executed together with their parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the URI that is being called with the following regex:

Pattern: `^https://(.*)\.zoom.us/j/(\d+)\?pwd=(.*)$`

Replace into: `zoommtg://zoom.us/join?confno=$2&pwd=$3`

For example:
`https://your-organization.zoom.us/j/123456789?pwd=asdfasdfasdfasdf`
becomes
`zoommtg://zoom.us/join?confno=123456789&pwd=asdfasdfasdf`